# Spring converter not called in requests using kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

Hello I'm creating Kotlin project using spring webflux. I created a converter accept enum field upper or lower case in request:

```
@Component
class WarehousesTypeEnumConverter : Converter<String, WarehousesType?>{

    companion object {
        private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WarehousesTypeEnumConverter::class.java)
    }

    override fun convert(value: String): WarehousesType? =
        try {
            log.info("try to convert {} to {}", value, WarehousesType::class.java)
            WarehousesType.valueOf(value.uppercase())
        }catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){
            log.error("error to convert {} to {}", value, WarehousesType::class.java)
            throw e
        }

    }
```

When I work with Java this work perfectly, I don't need more configuration but using Kotlin my application dont't call my converter. I try this, try register my converter in addFormatters in WebFluxConfigurer class and noting. thank you.

Comment: make sure the kotlin source folder is included in build, also verify the package

Comment: like this?

sourceSets {
  getByName("main").java.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
  getByName("test").java.srcDirs("src/test/kotlin")
}

I set this code in my build.gradle.kts and dind't work

Comment: I have also gone down this rabbit trail and could not get a Converter working with unit tests, despite spring validation stating that Converters will get pulled in and even registering things myself. I found that the DefaultConversionService is getting pulled in and using those converters regardless of anything I do.